# How to increase and decrease Volume > Media Volume using Appium (Android)

Tags: appium

I am automating Snapchat application where I have to deal with some video which comes with sound. I have to mute and unmute Media volume to view Video with and without Sound. Right now I am using below piece of code to mute and unmute but it is handing the System Ringtone not System Media.

```
driver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.VOLUME_MUTE));
driver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.VOLUME_UP));
```

How to control Media Volume in Android using Appium?

Comment: Welcome. `I am using below piece of code`: ?? Please edit question and add that. Else your question will eventually get closed. And take some to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key presses on appium are done by 
`driver.press_keycode(code)`

[All  required codes can be found here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html)

- 24 - KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP
- 25 - KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN

So in your case, 
final code would be like,

`driver.press_keycode(24)` - for volume up

`driver.press_keycode(25)` - for volume down